# Multiple controls in one itemtemplate - GridView

Tags: c#, gridview

I have a gridview in web application which show textboxes in each columns in page load event. Now what I want to do is to add another label control in this itemtemplate. Show that when I type something in the textbox and click save, I can show the label instead of the textbox to my database. I got the saving part work fine but not sure how to show the text I typed in a label. What I have right now is after I clicked the save button, the textbox stay in the gridview and label not show up. Any idea how to fix this?

```
<asp:GridView ID='gvMain' ruant="server">
   <Columns>
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText ="LastName">
         <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtFName" runat="server"/>
            <asp:Label ID="lblFName" ruant="server" />
   </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Please see this link for reference.

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Adding-Dynamic-Rows-in-ASP.Net-GridView-Control-with-TextBoxes.aspx

Comment: Not sure what you need. Do you need to see text in lblFName when you type it in txtFName? Or, do you need to show a label when you display data and show a textbox when you edit data?

Comment: Hi Gosha, yes. I need to see the text in lblFName (what I typed in my textbox) after I click the save button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add both controls to a cell item template and hide/show them based on if I save a row or add a new one. So, my code would be like the following:

Markup:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:GridView ID="Gridview1" runat="server" ShowFooter="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="RowNumber" HeaderText="Row Number" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Header 1">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Column1") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Header 2">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Column2") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Header 3">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Column3") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="ButtonAdd" runat="server" Text="Add New Row"
                            OnClick="ButtonAdd_Click" />
                        <asp:Button ID="ButtonSave" runat="server" Text="Save"
                            OnClick="ButtonSave_Click" />
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
</form>
```

Code-behind:

```
private void SetInitialRow() {
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    DataRow dr = null;
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("RowNumber", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column1", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column2", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column3", typeof(string)));
    dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["RowNumber"] = 1;
    dr["Column1"] = string.Empty;
    dr["Column2"] = string.Empty;
    dr["Column3"] = string.Empty;
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);

    Table = dt;

    BindGrid();
    SwitchMode(false);
}

private void AddNewRowToGrid() {
    if(Table != null) {
        DataRow row = Table.NewRow();
        Table.Rows.Add(row);
        BindGrid();
        SwitchMode(false);
    }
    else {
        Response.Write("ViewState is null");
    }
}

private void SaveRow() {
    if(Table != null) {
        int rowIndex = Table.Rows.Count - 1;
        TextBox box1 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("TextBox1");
        TextBox box2 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox2");
        TextBox box3 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("TextBox3");
        Table.Rows[rowIndex]["Column1"] = box1.Text;
        Table.Rows[rowIndex]["Column2"] = box2.Text;
        Table.Rows[rowIndex]["Column3"] = box3.Text;
        BindGrid();
        SwitchMode(true);
    }
    else {
        Response.Write("ViewState is null");
    }
}

private void SwitchMode(bool add) {
    Button saveBtn = (Button)Gridview1.FooterRow.Cells[3].FindControl("ButtonSave");
    saveBtn.Visible = !add;
    Button addBtn = (Button)Gridview1.FooterRow.Cells[3].FindControl("ButtonAdd");
    addBtn.Visible = add;
    SwitchControl(add);
}

private void SwitchControl(bool add) {
    for(int i = 0; i < Table.Rows.Count; i++) {
        bool txtVisible = false;
        if (i == Table.Rows.Count - 1) {
            txtVisible = !add;
        }
        TextBox box1 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[i].Cells[1].FindControl("TextBox1");
        box1.Visible = txtVisible;
        TextBox box2 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[i].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox2");
        box2.Visible = txtVisible;
        TextBox box3 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[i].Cells[3].FindControl("TextBox3");
        box3.Visible = txtVisible;
        Label label1 = (Label)Gridview1.Rows[i].Cells[1].FindControl("Label1");
        label1.Visible = !txtVisible;
        Label label2 = (Label)Gridview1.Rows[i].Cells[2].FindControl("Label2");
        label2.Visible = !txtVisible;
        Label label3 = (Label)Gridview1.Rows[i].Cells[3].FindControl("Label3");
        label3.Visible = !txtVisible;
    }
}

private DataTable Table {
    get {
        return ViewState["CurrentTable"] as DataTable;
    }
    set {
        ViewState["CurrentTable"] = value;
    }
}

private void BindGrid() {
    Gridview1.DataSource = Table;
    Gridview1.DataBind();
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if(!Page.IsPostBack) {
        SetInitialRow();
    }
}

protected void ButtonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    AddNewRowToGrid();
}

protected void ButtonSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    SaveRow();
}
```

So, first I see the Grid with one row and I can populate it with data via TextBoxes and click Save. Then, TextBoxes become Labels and Add New Row is visible. If I click it, a new row with TextBoxes appears.

Comment: thank you, I will give it a try. Thanks for your effort

Comment: just a question, why are you using`if (i == Table.Rows.Count - 1) {
            txtVisible = !add;
        }` this row, what exacting does it do?

Comment: @DragonBorn Well, with my approach only the last row has either TextBoxes or Labels. All previous rows have only Labels. That's what I check in the condition. To determine if I need to render TextBoxes or Labels, the "add" variable is used.